# VBA in Excel - use loop counter to reference cells

Tags: vba, loops, reference, cell, counter

I have cells that are either "True" or "False". I have names for these cells so that it's easier for me to reference in my codes. For Example, instead of saying cell "A1" I say cell "Apples". The cell names are: 
Apples
Oranges
Onions
Potatoes
Bananas

In a separate worksheet I have under column A:
Apples
Oranges
Bananas
This range of cells is named "Fruit". So this list is meant to be a list of the cell names I want to check.

I want to use a for loop to check if each cell referenced under in the range "Fruit" is true. This is my code:

```
For Each item In [Fruit]
    If Worksheets("Inventory").Range(item).Value = True Then
        --Do stuff--
    End If
Next item
```

I keep getting an error when trying to reference the cell. How can I do this? Is it possible for me to use the counter to reference the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

close...

```
For Each item In [Fruit]
    If Worksheets("Inventory").Range(item.Value) = True Then
        '--Do stuff--
    End If
Next item
```